# Kali Linux Running in AWS

Tags: ubuntu, security, amazon-web-services

Normally I run Kali in a virtualbox VM however due to the nature of a project it may be useful to run Kali from an AWS EC2 instance. So imagine my joy when I learned there was a Kali AMI only to be followed by disappointment that it is not available "to new users".

So what are my options now? Run a docker version of Kali? Run a debian and try to migrate to Kali. Install packages on my own (the default)? Other?

Or, is Kali a non-starter within AWS for "reasons"?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

For scanning, both Nessus and Qualys are approved by Amazon to provide those services without seeking permission. From where you run them, that's up to the client.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you're going to have some issues if you plan to do pen-testing in AWS. AWS explicitly disallows this sort of thing. I've got a NESSUS EC2 instance in AWS and AWS told me that I'm not even allowed to port scan my own network.

Comment: The rule is that you need to seek permission first. This is a standard web form where you detail source ip(s), destination ip(s), and a timeframe. This form is filled out from an account that has the correct ownership privleges. The form is at:  https://aws.amazon.com/forms/penetration-testing-request. With acceptance of the request I then used an AMI but I installed a number of tools. From that point I thought it would just be easier to have Kali.

Answer (score 0):

So the closest I have found is a compromise by creating a Debian/Ubuntu EC2 instance and then installing "katoolin" which enables you to install all the Kali distro tools.